# Splitting verbatim inside figure across pages

Tags: floats, page-breaking, verbatim

I want to include a long section of `verbatim` text, which is too long for a single page, inside a figure with a caption.
Unfortunately, when the `verbatim` environment is put into a figure, it does not automatically split across pages.
Here is a MWE that illustrates the problem which I am facing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % show diagram of page layout

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{verbatim}
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./2014-01-30.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file 2014-01-30.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./2014-01-30.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on 2014-01-30.pdf (1 page, 8170 bytes).
SyncTeX written on 2014-01-30.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on 2014-01-30.log.



This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./2014-01-30.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file 2014-01-30.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./2014-01-30.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on 2014-01-30.pdf (1 page, 8170 bytes).
SyncTeX written on 2014-01-30.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on 2014-01-30.log.



This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./2014-01-30.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file 2014-01-30.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./2014-01-30.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on 2014-01-30.pdf (1 page, 8170 bytes).
SyncTeX written on 2014-01-30.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on 2014-01-30.log.
\end{verbatim}
\caption{Three copies of output of \texttt{pdflatex}.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You won't *ever* get a page break within a standard `figure` environment, but don't worry, there are other options :) Have a look at the `listings` package which can provide you with an environment that has captions- the documentation has lots of examples, including some that `float`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Floating objects don't admit page breaks; you can use the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package to typeset your verbatim text; you can use the `caption` key to provide a caption and (unless you declare the listing as a float), it will admit page breaks:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % show diagram of page layout
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  columns=fullflexible
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Three copies of output of \texttt{pdflatex}.}]
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./2014-01-30.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file 2014-01-30.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./2014-01-30.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on 2014-01-30.pdf (1 page, 8170 bytes).
SyncTeX written on 2014-01-30.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on 2014-01-30.log.



This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./2014-01-30.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file 2014-01-30.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./2014-01-30.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on 2014-01-30.pdf (1 page, 8170 bytes).
SyncTeX written on 2014-01-30.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on 2014-01-30.log.



This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./2014-01-30.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file 2014-01-30.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./2014-01-30.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on 2014-01-30.pdf (1 page, 8170 bytes).
SyncTeX written on 2014-01-30.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on 2014-01-30.log.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you want to add a bit of 'bling' to your `verbatim` you can, for example, employ the [`tcolorbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox) package.

[image: screenshot]

In the code below, I have defined a new `newtcblisting` called `cmhlisting` which takes two mandatory arguments, and one optional:

- `[#1]` is optional arguments that you wish to pass to the `listings` environment
- `{#2}` is the caption
- `{#3}` is the `\label` that can be used for `\ref` and friends

Here's the complete code- if you want it to `float`, then you need only uncomment the lines that detail `float` and `floatplacement`. The manual details lots and lots of other options- this is just something to get you started.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
% tcolorbox libraries
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins,listings}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
    addtolol/.style={list entry={\kvtcb@title},add to list={lol}{lstlisting}},
}
\makeatother

\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{cmhlisting}[3][]{%
    width=\textwidth,
    breakable,
    colback=blue!5!white,
    colframe=white!85!black,
    listing only,
    listing options={#1},
    center title,
    %float,
    %floatplacement=!ht,
    title={\color{black}{\scshape Listing \thetcbcounter}: ~#2},label={#3},
    addtolol,
}

\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
      columns=fullflexible,
}%
\begin{document}

reference: \ref{lst:yourlabelhere}

\begin{cmhlisting}{Three copies of output of \texttt{pdflatex}}{lst:yourlabelhere}
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./2014-01-30.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file 2014-01-30.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./2014-01-30.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on 2014-01-30.pdf (1 page, 8170 bytes).
SyncTeX written on 2014-01-30.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on 2014-01-30.log.



This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./2014-01-30.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file 2014-01-30.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./2014-01-30.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on 2014-01-30.pdf (1 page, 8170 bytes).
SyncTeX written on 2014-01-30.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on 2014-01-30.log.



This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./2014-01-30.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file 2014-01-30.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./2014-01-30.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on 2014-01-30.pdf (1 page, 8170 bytes).
SyncTeX written on 2014-01-30.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on 2014-01-30.log.
\end{cmhlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is interesting, and it looks great. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried to compile your code, but I get an error `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   [
l.15 \newtcblisting[u` Do you have any idea why I might be getting this error?

Comment: @ILiketoCode works fine for me (as is). Try copying and pasting it into a new file- sounds like you have modified it

Comment: I tried to copy and paste into a new file, and it doesn't work. Strange!

Comment: @ILiketoCode I guess it's a version problem because the code works fine for me. You should check if `tcolorbox` version `v2.61 (2014/01/10)` or `v2.70 (2014/02/06)` is installed. I guess `v2.51 (2013/09/16)` could also be new enough (I have not tested this).

Comment: You're right. Once I installed `v2.61` it worked fine.

Comment: @ILiketoCode see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) for details of updating :)