# Captions for tcolorbox

Tags: captions, tcolorbox

I would like to add captions to a `tcolorbox` structure. How can I do so? The standard `\caption{}` construct does not work in this case. Or is there a way to make the same thing (but with captions) without using `tcolorbox`?

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{verbatim}
{'maxs': [0.0,
  0.0006787988281249935,
  0.00032118164062514,
  0.0001609179687499518],
 'means': [0.0,
  0.00013521044921876194,
  8.352197265622923e-05,
  4.6293782552030614e-05]}
\end{verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the `title` for this. Note that `tcolorbox` has some tremendous support for listings.

Comment: @sequence -- please have a look at the answer below if it meets the requirement

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this as adapted from --

[Splitting verbatim inside figure across pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156788/splitting-verbatim-inside-figure-across-pages)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins,listings}

\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{cmhlisting}[3][]{%
    width=\textwidth,
    colback=blue!5!white,
    colframe=white!85!black,
    listing only,
    listing options={#1},
    center title,
    %breakable,
    %float,
    %floatplacement=!ht,
    title={\color{black}{\scshape My Caption \thetcbcounter}: ~#2}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{cmhlisting}{Caption with verbatim in  \texttt{tcolorbox}}
'maxs': [0.0,
    0.0006787988281249935,
    0.00032118164062514,
    0.0001609179687499518],
    'means': [0.0,
    0.00013521044921876194,
    8.352197265622923e-05,
    4.6293782552030614e-05]
\end{cmhlisting}
\end{document}
```